# I think my PC case power button messes with my Windows when it's in sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power

I have Corsair 5000d and its power button has (at least a feeling of) 2-step click to it, so a gentle press clicks it once and a harder press makes 2 sequential clicks.

When I put my Windows 10 in sleep mode I can only "wake it up" using the harder press, and if I do the gentle press (1 click) it seemingly does nothing, and then a hard press turns the computer on as if it was shut down.

My guess is that the gentle click clears the RAM somehow and turns the PC off. (maybe it's faulty and causes a short?) I even got this screen once:

[image]

CPU: i7 12700f
MOBO: PRO B660M-A DDR4 with latest BIOS release `7D43v13`

And my questions are: is it really the power button? Or is it something in the operating system which only by chance looks like it's the power button's fault? If it's the button, is it simply faulty or is it likely that I didn't connect some wires correctly in the PC?

Comment: @Ramhound .. More modern? .. Please educate me on why that matters.  S1->S3 are still completely supported by ACPI.  Sleep takes like 1 second (or less on my machine).  Hibernation takes like *more* seconds.  S1->S3 never actually shut the machine down.  S4 does.  I am honestly asking, not trolling.  You are wise so I am asking.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Hibernation is actually not more modern than Sleep. Standby came first, then hibernation, then sleep, and the S number only states how deep the sleep is, but not when it was introduced. Either state is actually fine, but the powerbutton itself sounds bad. I haven't seen any pc or case with 2 states of powerbutton. A quick check for this particular case does not mention this as a special feature either. I think the powerbutton is damaged or maybe it is not pressed down correctly and somehow hangs in the socket.